# Determining working directory of another program

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any way of determining the current working directory of an already running program in Linux?

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to be able to work in a terminal and then have a keyboard shortcut set up which will run a tool which I am writing which displays a little popup window containing some information and a few buttons to perform actions. This tool requires a working directory so that it knows what data to work on and I want to be able to set it up so that it will work on the directory in which I am working in the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/proc/PID/cwd is a symlink to PIDs working directory:

```
jesperes@virtual-ubuntu $ ls /proc/self/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jesperes 0 2009-05-29 18:56 /proc/self/cwd -> /home/jesperes/hacks
jesperes@virtual-ubuntu $
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do for my needs! :-P

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [getcwd()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd)

There is also a symlink to the cwd in /proc/[pid]/cwd